# Pontryagin-dual of the torsion subgroup of oriented bordism group

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes, cobordism

Consider the oriented cobordism group of $BG$ with $U(1)$ coefficient $\Omega_{SO}^d(BG,U(1))$ with a finite discrete group $G$.

> question: Explain or show that the Pontryagin-dual of the torsion subgroup of oriented bordism group $\Omega_{SO,d}(BG)$ is
>   $$\frac{\text{Hom}(\Omega_{SO,d}(BG),U(1))}{ \text{im}(f)}.\;\;\;\; (?)$$

where $f$ is a map from $f: \text{Hom}(\Omega_{SO,d}(G),\mathbb{R}) \to \text{Hom}(\Omega_{SO,d}(G),U(1))$.
The image of the $f$ map is composed by elements of $\text{Hom}(\Omega_{SO,d}(BG),U(1))$ that vanish on the torsion subgroup of bordism group $\Omega_{SO,d}(BG)$.